# XAML GridView template bind to item

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, data-binding

This seems like a tricky one. At least, it's tricky to describe.

Basically, I'm setting the itemsSource of a GridView to a list of objects, and I want each item in the GridView to have access to the object it was generated by in its own code.

Here are some snippets that I hope should say what I mean:

ReadingPage.xaml.cs

```
zoomedInGrid.ItemsSource = openChapters.chapters; //A List<BibleChapter>
```

ReadingPage.xaml

```
<GridView x:Name="zoomedInGrid">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <local:ChapterBox Chapter="" />
           <!--I have no idea what to put here^^^-->
       </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And then in ChapterBox.xaml.cs I need to have access to the BibleChapter that the templated ChapterBox was created for.

Anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT**

This is what I have in ChapterBox.xaml.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChapterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Chapter",
        typeof(BibleChapter),
        typeof(ChapterBox),
        null);

public BibleChapter Chapter
{
    get { return (BibleChapter)GetValue(ChapterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChapterProperty, value); }
}

public ChapterBox()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    VerseRichTextBuilder builder = new VerseRichTextBuilder();
    builder.Build(textBlock, Chapter); //<== Chapter is null at this point
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dependency property to the `ChapterBox` class, and then use a two-way binding in the XAML:

```
<local:ChapterBox Chapter="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The DP would look like this (assume you're using WPF, but it's similar for Silverlight):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChapterProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Chapter", 
        // property type
        typeof(BibleChapter), 
        // property owner type
        typeof(ChapterBox), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChapterChanged)));

public static void OnChapterChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var chapterBox = (ChapterBox)sender;

    VerseRichTextBuilder builder = new VerseRichTextBuilder();
    var newValue = (Chapter)args.NewValue;
    builder.Build(chapterBox.textBlock, newValue); 
}

public BibleChapter Chapter
{
    get { return (BibleChapter)GetValue(ChapterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChapterProperty, value); }
}
```

Notice that the `ChapterProperty` DP is actually the binding *source*, while the view model property (`BibleChapter`) is the target.  However, when you set `Mode=TwoWay`, it causes the property to update the source from the target.

Comment: Wow, that was amazingly simple! It seems like it should all work, but in the constructor for ChapterBox(), Chapter is **null** (code entered in question, above). If it is supposed to be null in the constructor, at what point will it change and how can I make builder.Build() run once it does?

Comment: @MoscowModder you can probably use the property-changed handler for that -- see update above.

Answer (score 1):

If `Chapter` is a DependencyProperty, then you can simply do:

```
<local:ChapterBox Chapter="{Binding}" />
```

This will set the instance of the individual item to be bound to whatever `Chapter` is, obviously if the types don't match you can use a converter. Alternatively, you should probably look at simply setting the `DataContext` of the user control:

```
<local:ChapterBox DataContext="{Binding}" ... />
```